# Axios doesn't resolve subdomains when making requests to Local Area Network (e.g. 'http://us.192.168.1.25:8080/auth')

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, http, axios, subdomain

I use React-Native for an app and Spring Boot for backend. For making requests from the app, I use Axios.

I am developing a new backend service and I wanted to test it on the app before making a backend deploy. Usually, I would simply use something like `axios.post('http://192.168.1.25:8080/resource')`, to access the server running on my PC connected to the smartphone via LAN. It works.

This new service, however, depends on the subdomain sent with the the HTTP request. For instance, on the previous example, I would have to make a post to `'http://english.192.168.1.25:8080/resource'`. Making a axios.post() to that address however, doesn't work. Axios gives me the error "can't resolve `english.192.168.1.25`".

Does anyone know how to solve this? Testing with Postman from another machine, the endpoint `'http://english.192.168.1.25:8080/resource'` works just fine (Only the axios lib running on the react-native phone fails).

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;**
try to disable your dns-rebind protection in your router by adding an exception for your subdomain.localhost

FritzBox -> Home Network -> Network settings -> DNS Rebind Protection

the other way would be to run your own dns on your system which does the same. Something like dnsmasq or https://github.com/hubdotcom/marlon-tools/blob/master/tools/dnsproxy/dnsproxy.py

---

I think i found a solution for this problem. something.localhost is routed to your primary dns. In a typically installation its your router. Most modern routers have a dns-rebind-security mechanism. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding

I ran into the same issue at home and when i tried to get foo.localhost running at work, it works as expected. So what can I say. At home we use a FritzBox 7560 with DNS Rebind protection enabled. At work I have a noname router from a "magenta company" without a rebind protection.